# PeopleEditor very slow in IE in application page having no master page

Tags: master-page, people-picker, application-pages

I am using PeopleEditor in an application page which has master page file as follows:

```
DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"
```

**Code**

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="pp" MultiSelect="true" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" Width="250px" SelectionSet="User" />
```

It works fine.

But when I use same PeopleEditor in an application page which has not master page then the page (that opens in browser) becomes very slow and I cannot even click inside PeopleEditor control to write anything as browser stops responding. I had to close the browser then. It happens only in IE.

Code

```
<form runat="server"><SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="pp" MultiSelect="true" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" Width="250px" SelectionSet="User" /></form>
```

Looks like it requires some SharePoint JS/CSS files to work properly which are available only when using master page in an application page.

Has anyone used PeopleEditor in an application page which has no master page?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by copying/pasting all CSS/JS files being used in header from another application page which is using master page into this one. But I wonder why the problem only happens in IE!